# Error while installing boost_1_54

Tags: linux, c++

On trying to install boost I get this error during configuration checks. Googling did not give any pointers.

```
[root@heracles boost_1_54_0]# ./b2 install
Performing configuration checks

    - 32-bit                   : no  (cached)
    - 64-bit                   : yes (cached)
    - arm                      : no  (cached)
    - mips1                    : no  (cached)
    - power                    : no  (cached)
    - sparc                    : no  (cached)
    - x86                      : yes (cached)
error: No best alternative for libs/coroutine/build/allocator_sources
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <target-os>windows <threading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <segmented-stacks>on <threading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <threading>multi
        not matched
    - has_icu builds           : no  (cached)
warning: Graph library does not contain MPI-based parallel components.
note: to enable them, add "using mpi ;" to your user-config.jam
    - zlib                     : yes (cached)
    - iconv (libc)             : yes (cached)
    - icu                      : no  (cached)
    - icu (lib64)              : no  (cached)
    - compiler-supports-ssse3  : yes (cached)
    - compiler-supports-avx2   : no  (cached)
    - gcc visibility           : yes (cached)
    - long double support      : yes (cached)
warning: skipping optional Message Passing Interface (MPI) library.
note: to enable MPI support, add "using mpi ;" to user-config.jam.
note: to suppress this message, pass "--without-mpi" to bjam.
note: otherwise, you can safely ignore this message.
error: No best alternative for libs/coroutine/build/allocator_sources
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <target-os>windows <threading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <segmented-stacks>on <threading>multi
        not matched
    next alternative: required properties: <link>static <threading>multi
        not matched
    - zlib                     : yes (cached)
```

How can the alternative for allocator sources be located?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

This is a bug in boost. To fix it open the file `lib/coroutine/build/Jamfile.v2` and replace this line:

```
explicit yield_sources ;
```

With this one:

```
explicit allocator_sources ;
```

or wait on the bugfix-release.

Comment: A bit dated, but note that patches are available [here](http://www.boost.org/patches/). In addition to this bug, there are three other patches currently available against 1.54.0.

Comment: That worked, though I think "lib" should be "libs" above.